# search for list items within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I know i can search for list items within a string like this:

```
values = ['XX', 'ZI']
if any(val in my_string  for val in values):
        print('priting', my_string )
```

However, in this way, I cannot access the list values after the if statement. I want to print the `value`which is present within the `my_string` as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and you can handle every item separately.

Comment: `for val in values: if <match>: <do whatever>`?

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least two solutions to that.

The first is using a loop, as told in the comments:

```py
my_string = 'Test XX'
values = ['XX', 'ZI']

for val in values:
    if val in my_string:
        print(val)
```

Another solution would be to use `filter()` to get the list of matches

```py
my_string = 'Test XX'
values = ['XX', 'ZI']

matches = filter(lambda val: val in my_string, values)
print(list(matches))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex approach here:

```py
my_string = "Bacardi XX Rum and ZIP codes"
values = ['XX', 'ZI', 'QQ']
regex = r'(' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in values]) + r')'
matches = re.findall(regex, my_string)
print(matches)  # ['XX', 'ZI']
```

Here we build an alternation of values, then do an exhaustive regex search for each value against the input string.  Only matching values will be captured and printed at the end.

Comment: This might work well unless there are regular expressions syntax elements in `values`. A `(` is enough to break it.

Comment: @KlausD. You're right...I have updated to `re.escape` each list item before building the alternation. Y

Comment: I think this might give incomplete results if a search value itself is part for another search value. ie. with `values = ['XX', 'XXH', 'ZI', 'QQ']` and `my_string = "Bacardi XXH Rum and ZIP codes"` will only match with `XX` and `ZI`. Not sure if it would be an issue for this specific use case, but this info should be taken in account

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string function, find() to do the task.

```
  matching_strings = filter(lambda val : string.find(val,0,len(string)) != -1,values)
  print(list(matching_strings))
```